# Musical chords including slash chords regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I found a great regex musical chords on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dGrpi7/1).

However, slash chords such as D/F#, Bb/C, B7/F#, Em/G, etc. don't match. Please help.

Comment: Are you certain that `D/F#` is a valid/typical way of writing a particular chord?  Maybe the regex doesn't support your additional inputs because the syntax is off.

Comment: Yes. It's valid. Some popular site like Ultimateguitar has it too. For example:
https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/ed-sheeran/thinking-out-loud-chords-1486866

Comment: You might be chasing a diminishing (pun intended) goal, in that std chord notation is not likely regular.  For example, is 1m7 distinct from 1m7m7?  Are 1b5m7 and 1m7b5 the same?

Comment: @mevets the `b` modifies the preceding key, i.e. `Db` identifies the half-note between C and D (equivalent to C#, where # is "and a half" and b is "minus a half". Traditionally C# and Db had slightly different frequencies, but in modern usage they are both defined as exactly one half note. The musical scale has several special cases, like there is no Fb, or rather it's equivalent to E, and similarly for the interval B-C). But there *are* stacking modifiers like Cm7(b5)

Comment: @triplee iib5, in C would be Ddim, not (Db)5.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:[ABCDEFG](?:#|b)?)(?:\/[ABCDEFG]b)` this part in the original regex should match the form `X/Y`.

But it seems the author think the `Y` part can only end in `b` not `#`. Not a music guy cannot tell why.

Anyway, here’s the fix. Replace the above with `(?:[ABCDEFG](?:#|b)?)(?:\/[ABCDEFG][#b])` to include a **required** suffix of either `b` or `#`. Is this correct music wise?

Comment: It doesn't work. Thanks for your input though on where the part should be edited. I somehow test it in someway from your [#b] to [#|b]. However, the sharp at the end doesn't match. Only the D/F, not D/F#.

Comment: In most regex dialects there is no need to backslash the slash. Of course, the OP should clarify which dialect they are targeting. Out of Perl/PCRE-compatible implementations, I guess it's only strictly necessary in PHP (though the _default_ regex separator in Perl is also a slash; but you are encouraged to use a different separator if your regex contains literal slashes precisely so you don't need to backslash them).

Comment: `[b|#]` means one out of `b`, `|` or `#`. That's not correct.

Comment: Like the examples in the question reveal, `#` or `b` are optonal in both subexpressions, both before and after the slash. The same notation should probably be used on both sides, `[#b]?` is more compact and idiomatic (as well as compatible with more regex dialects) than the clunky `(?:b|#)?`

Comment: @tripleee I'm going to use it in javascript. Thanks for that. I added javascript tag in my question.

Comment: Well then, that's why `(?:...)` didn't work.

Comment: The examples also have an optional `m` for minor after the key. For example, `C#m`. A more complex example still would have a number, too, like `C#m7`

Comment: @enrique The problem is actually caused by the surrounding `\b` pair at the start and end of regex. If you remove them it'll work. I think it's safe to not include `\b` for this use case.

Comment: Reason being `\b` will also match `/` and `#`, and such behavior corrupts the sequence.